# Function that returns int array[] or pointer to int array[] back to calling routine in C

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers, return

How can I make this function return `int array[4]` or pointer to `*array[4]` ? 
This array with 4 integers is calculated in ascending order via pointers and bubble sort in the scope of this function and then returns to main to print.

I can print this array in the scope of this fuction but I'm wondering can I pass it back to main (calling function)?

`void sort4(int *n1, int *n2, int *n3, int *n4)` if I change it to 
`int X[4] sort4(int *n1, int *n2, int *n3, int *n4)` doesn't work. And this too

```
int *X[4] sort4(int *n1, int *n2, int *n3, int *n4)
```

Comment: I want to make sure I understand. You pass the addresses of the four integers, and want to return an array containing their values sorted? Why pass addresses?

Comment: Are you sure it won't be simpler to sort the four integers so that `*n1 <= *n2 <= *n3 <= *n4`?

Comment: https://codeshare.io/5Pdd7X

Comment: You want the variables you passed to be sorted in the end or not?

Comment: Yes, and they are sorted. if you print Arr they are sorted. But how can I return the entire array back to the calling routine? @ StoryTeller

Comment: They aren't sorted. The array that contains the **copies of their values** is sorted.

Comment: no way to do I want?@StoryTeller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to sort four individual integers in ascending order, and you pass their addresses, you need to make sure that you swap the **pointees**. Here's your code amended with the correct pointer arithmetic:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void sort4(int *n1, int *n2, int *n3, int *n4)
{
    int *Arr[] = { n1, n2, n3, n4 };
    int **i = Arr, **j, temp;
    int  ** const arrayEnd = Arr + 4;

    for (; i != arrayEnd - 1; i++)
        for (j = i + 1; j != arrayEnd; j++)
            if (**i > **j) {
                temp = **i;
                **i = **j;
                **j = temp;
            }  
}

int main(void)
{
    int i1 = 125;
    int i2 = 100;
    int i3 = 10;
    int i4 = 50;

    printf("i1 = %i, i2 = %i, i3 = %i, i4 = %i\n", i1, i2, i3, i4);

    sort4(&i1, &i2, &i3, &i4);

    printf("i1 = %i, i2 = %i, i3 = %i, i4 = %i\n", i1, i2, i3, i4);

    return 0;
}
```

[Output](http://ideone.com/YvKlMW):

> i1 = 125, i2 = 100, i3 = 10, i4 = 50
>   i1 = 10, i2 = 50, i3 = 100, i4 = 125

Comment: Thank you! If I wanted to return entire Arr[4]  back to main? void sort4 function  end with this last line of code ( return Arr; ). Is it possible?

Comment: sort4 function would be no longer void it would be int that return array or pointer to array Arr.

Comment: @Yellowfun - No. It will decay into an address to the first element. And you will return an address to something that goes out of scope, a dangling pointer. You can try just accepting an array to fill from the calling code.